# Extracting values from object variable for use in a lookup within dynamic resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Trying to extract lookup an object within dynamic blocks without much luck.

```
variable "myobjectvar" {
 type = object({
   var1 = string
   var2 = string
   var3 = number})
  }
  



  dynamic "resource1 {
    for_each = var.var1
    
    content {
      domainname = resource1.value.domainname
      myobjectvar_id = lookup(myobjectvar.value, "var1", myobjectvar.key)
      
      dynamic "resource2" {
        for_each = lenght(lookup(myobjectvar.value),"custom_myobjectvar_config", "")) = ? [] : [lookup(myobjectvar.value), "custom_myobjectvar_config",""] 
        content {
          http_port = lookup(custom_myobjectvar_config.value, "var2", 80)}
    }
  
  }
```

i've tried to replace

```
 http_port = lookup(custom_myobjectvar_config.value, "http_port", 80)}
```

with

```
 http_port = var.myobjectvar.http_port
```

I need to extract domainname and http_port. How do I do this?

Comment: Would you be able to show the resource you are trying to do this with?

Comment: Could you also please tidy up the code that you have posted? Braces aren't matching, functions are misspelt, etc, so it is hard to be sure that whatever problem you are facing isn't just a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using for the lookup function looks to be wrong. According to the [documentation](https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-lookup), the below is how the lookup function is called:

`lookup(map name, key, default_value)`

Which will loosely translate to

`myobjectvar_id = lookup(myobjectvar.value, "var3", "number")`

myobjectvar.key - as a default value will return error as your reference is wrong. Share your code snippet and the error you are seeing to debug further.